# sklearn tree treats categorical variable as float during splits, how should I solve this?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm having trouble with my regression tree using the sklearn package. It's about a book dataset, in which the regression tree can be seen below:

[image: sklearn tree]

The problem is in the `STORY_LANGUAGE` variable. This is a categorical variable with the values 0, 1, 2, and 3, which all correspond to a different language of the book. Before running the model, I've made sure that `STORY_LANGUAGE` is a categorical variable, yet the tree still splits it and treats it as a float (1.5).

How should I solve this? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing a list of integers as features to scikit-learn, you're telling it that there's some sort dependence between the features. That e.g. `0` is closer related to `1` than to `2`. To get around this, you will need to do one-hot encoding with the built-in [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html). If you have three categories, `0`, `1` and `2`, a `0` will be converted to `[1,0,0]`, while a `1` will be converted to `[0,1,0]`. Basically your one feature is replaced with a vector that is equal to `1` at a position corresponding to which class it is and `0` otherwise.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

# Generate random integers between 0 and 2
x = np.random.randint(0,3, size=(100,1))
# Create the one-hot encoder object, specifying not to use sparse arrays.
m = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
# Transform your features
x_one_hot = m.fit_transform(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sklearn's DecisionTreeRegressor, your label encoded features will simply be treated as numerical features. If you want them to be treated as categories, you can either perform one-hot-encoding (e.g. using [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)) or use an algorithm that supports categorical features out of the box (e.g. lightGBM).